# relevant pure math for optimization

Tags: soft-question, optimization, learning

I'm interested in optimization generally. I don't know enough to break it down to sub-fields that I would work on.

Probability and statistics seem relevant. What about calculus of variations/functional analysis? Can anyone explain how they fit into the bigger picture (if at all)? What else should I know about? My school does not have a class on functional analysis, but on "Banach Algebras and Spectral Theory".

Comment: You certainly would want to check the officially free to download "Convex Optimization" book of Boyd and Vandenberghe, at http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/

Comment: That is a broad question. Get several books by that title and look at prerequisites. Also look at several schools that have specialization in optimization and look at their courses. Programming, advanced calculus,  linear algebra, linear programming, and specialty course in differential equations, applied math will be needed.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend a course in linear programming after taking linear algebra.  Take a look at "Introduction to Operations Research" by Hillier and Lieberman.  A similar book is written by Wayne Winston.  I also recommend reading the introduction to "Optimization by Vector Space Methods" by Luenberger if you are interested in how functional analysis relates to optimization.